# finding the centroid of composite areas.

Tags: calculus, geometry

[image: QUOTE]

I've been staring at this problem for hours. It seems so straight forward. I'm asked to find the centroid of this figure shown. The y coordinate to be exaxt. The book gets 135mm but I don't understand how they could get that since the area of the trapezoid is the same as the area of the rectangle so the coordinates would have to be further up. Could someone explain why this is so?

Comment: 135 is the distance measured down from the top of the figure.

Comment: But how do I know i measure from there? Why not from bottom to top. That's the way I saw the problem at first glance

Comment: @adam Because $\overline{y}$ is shown to be the distance from the top to $C$ in the figure.

Comment: Oh I see.... how silly of me to miss that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

divide the total area to rectangle and triangle as shown in Fig.1
[image]

Tha total area is
$$A_t=(900*80)+(360*100)+0.5(100*360)+0.5*(100*360)=144000$$

To find the $X_y$, we will take the moment about $x-axis$
$$M_x=(900*80)(400)+(100*360)(180)+0.5(100*360)(240)+0.5(100*360)(240)=43920000$$

$$Y_c=\frac{M_x}{A_t}=\frac{43920000}{144000}=305 mm$$

if you need to find it respect to the top edge, you should subtract it from $440$

$$440-305=135 mm$$